# python aiohttp behaving like single threaded application

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have the following simple python web server application. When I trigger /sleep call - until the time for sleep ends and the response returns - all other calls on /quick are blocked. I am not sure what it wrong with this code. Can someone provide some clarity?

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio
import time

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

async def sleephandle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    time.sleep(12) // trivializing here; actual code has a transition from async to sync 
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

async def init(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_get('/quick', handle)
    app.router.add_get('/sleep', sleephandle)
    srv = await loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), '127.0.0.1', 8000)
    print('server started')
    return srv

def create_server():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
    loop.run_forever()

create_server()
```

Comment: One problem is that `time.sleep` is blocking. You want to use `await asyncio.sleep(12)` instead.

Comment: thanks for the response.. i had sleep there to represent a long running task.. in the actual code I am trying to debug - instead of sleep - it transitions from async to sync..

Comment: Same problem. asyncio is single threaded so as soon as it encounters a long, synchronous task, everything else is blocked waiting for it to complete and control to be yielded back to the event loop.

Comment: Is there a way to make the server handle multiple requests in parallel?

Comment: You either need to use code that is compatible with asyncio or look at using something like `asyncio.to_thread`. It’s hard to be more specific without real code.

Comment: What does "transition from async to sync" even mean? The code is async, so it 
should be transitioning from sync to async, if anything. Please edit the question to clarify precisely what you are attempting to do. The answer is probably to wrap your sync code in `asyncio.to_thread`, as suggested by dirn.

Comment: @RajkumarPurushothaman any feedback please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea of my solution is to use `loop.run_in_executor` with correct for your case Pool. You can solve the problem the following way:

```py
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio
import time
import logging
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime


def blocking_code():
    """Some long running code"""
    time.sleep(12)
    return "!!!!"


async def blocking_code_task(loop: asyncio.BaseEventLoop, request: web.Request):
    """Wrapper to be used in asyncio Task"""
    r = await loop.run_in_executor(executor=request.app["workers_pool"], func=blocking_code)
    logging.info(f"{datetime.now()}: {r}")


async def handle(request: web.Request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)


async def sleephandle(request: web.Request):
    """We wait fore results here, then send response"""
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # if you want to wait for result
    r = await loop.run_in_executor(executor=request.app["workers_pool"], func=blocking_code)
    text = "Hello, " + name + r
    return web.Response(text=text)


async def fast_sleep_answer(request: web.Request):
    """We send response as fast as possible and do all work in another asyncio Task"""
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # if you do not want to want for result
    asyncio.create_task(blocking_code_task(loop, request))
    text = "Fast answer" + name
    return web.Response(text=text)


async def on_shutdown(app):
    """Do not forget to correctly close ThreadPool"""
    app["workers_pool"].shutdown()
    logging.info(f"{datetime.now()}: Pool is closed")


async def init(args=None):
    """Changed your code for newer aiohttp"""
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(8)
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/quick', handle)
    app.router.add_get('/sleep', sleephandle)
    app.router.add_get('/fast', fast_sleep_answer)
    app["workers_pool"] = pool  # can be ThreadPool or ProcessPool
    app.on_shutdown.append(on_shutdown)  # close the pool when app closes
    return app

# the better way to tun app
# name of file is x.py
# in Linux command will be python3
# python -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8080 x:init
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    web.run_app(init(), host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

All blocking IN/OUT ops are made in ThreadPoolExecutor. If your tasks are CPU bound go with ProcessPoolExecutor. I showed two cases: 1) when you can't answer as fast as possible and need to wait for results 2) when you can just answer and then make all work in background.